# Cant connect to mongodb database using mongoose

Tags: node.js, docker, mongoose, koa, nodemon

Hey so i have a school assignment that requires me to connect to a mongodb database with mongoose and koa. I have my database set up on Docker and i can access it through mongodb Compass so that should be all right. But when i try to use mongoose, i get an error message on the docker display.

My code:

server.js

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const router = require('./routes');


const app = new Koa();
app.use(require('koa-body')());
app.use(router.routes());

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then(() => {
        const listener = app.listen(process.env.APP_PORT || 3000, () =>
            console.log('App started on port ' + listener.address().port)
        )
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
        process.exit(1)
    })

//    app.proxy = true;
module.exports = app;
```

docker-compose.yml

```
mongodb:
    image: 'mongo:4.4.0'
    command: '--auth'
    container_name: mongodb_container
    volumes:
      - './data/mongo:/data/db:delegated'
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    environment: 
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: database1

  node-service-two:
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    build:
      context: '../Test-II-node'
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - '../Test-I-node:/home/node/app:delegated'
    environment:
      MONGODB_URI: mongodb://root:example@localhost:27017/two?authSource=admin
    command: 'run dev'
```

scripts from package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node src/server.js",
    "dev": "nodemon src/server.js"
  }
```

the error message

```
[nodemon] starting `node src/server.js`

MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017

at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/home/node/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:800:32)

at /home/node/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:341:10

at /home/node/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:31:5

at new Promise (<anonymous>)

at promiseOrCallback (/home/node/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:30:10)

at Mongoose.connect (/home/node/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:340:10)

at Object.<anonymous> (/home/node/app/src/server.js:11:10)

at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1075:30)

at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1096:10)

at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:940:32)

at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:781:14)

at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)

at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {

reason: TopologyDescription {

type: 'Single',

setName: null,

maxSetVersion: null,

maxElectionId: null,

servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },

stale: false,

compatible: true,

compatibilityError: null,

logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,

heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,

localThresholdMS: 15,

commonWireVersion: null

}
}

[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Im pretty sure its got something to do with the javascript promise or it cant find the mongodb url but i havent been able to pinpoint the issue. I also have all the necessary packages installed. Its my first time using node so any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

When using docker-compose you have to remember that each service is its own container. when your Node.js service is looking for **localhost** it is looking at itself.

To fix this point mongoose at the MongoDB container by using its service name specified in your docker-compose: `MONGODB_URI: mongodb://root:example@mongodb:27017/two?authSource=admin`